# How to use object in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create object parameter some thing like this

```
sample_data=[{
                        name: 'new',
                        data: [1, 0, 2, 8, 1]
                    }, {
                        name: 'open',
                        data: [1, 2, 3, 7, 1]
                    },{
                        name: 'closed',
                        data: [5, 4, 3, 1, 1]
                    },{
                        name: 'onhold',
                        data: [1, 1, 2, 0, 1]
                    }, {
                        name: 'completed',
                        data: [0, 0, 5, 1, 2]
                    }];
```

I had totally 6 arrays all the name parameters in array1 and all data parameters in another arrays.

Is there any option to built object as my requirement above, using arrays that i have

**My arrays:**

```
name_array=Array("new","open","closed","onhold","completed");

    new_data=Array(1, 0, 2, 8, 1);
    open_data=Array(1, 2, 3, 7, 1);
    closed_data=Array(5, 4, 3, 1, 1);
    onhold_data=Array(1, 1, 2, 0, 1);
    completed_data=Array(0, 0, 5, 1, 2);
```

Help me how to create object using these array in javascript or jquery.

Comment: Since there are a flurry of similar answers, I'm just going to post this here as a reference. http://jsfiddle.net/mkmcdonald/RJSZ9/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution assumes your array objects are declared globally (on the window object).  Typically I would not suggest this type of thing, but this works:

```
var sampleData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < name_array.length; i++) {
    var arrayName = name_array[i];
    sampleData.push({
        name: arrayName,
        data: window[arrayName + "_data"]
    });
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/HzQvu/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you should be using is an object.

```
names = {
  "new" : Array(1, 0, 2, 8, 1),
  "open" : Array(1, 2, 3, 7, 1),
...
};
```

So to construct it given the `sample_data` above would be:

```
names = {};
for(var i =0; i<sample_data.length; i ++){
  names[sample_data[i].name] = sample_data[i].data;
}
```

You can then access the object as `names["new"]`  or `var which = "new";  names[which];` and so on, and iterate over the object if needed.

Answer (score 0):

With the eval() function...

```
var name_array=Array("new","open","closed","onhold","completed");

 var   new_data=Array(1, 0, 2, 8, 1);
   var  open_data=Array(1, 2, 3, 7, 1);
   var  closed_data=Array(5, 4, 3, 1, 1);
   var  onhold_data=Array(1, 1, 2, 0, 1);
  var   completed_data=Array(0, 0, 5, 1, 2);

$(function(){

  var combined = [];  
  for(var i = 0;i<name_array.length;i++)
  {
      combined.push({
          name: name_array[i],
          data: eval(name_array[i] + "_data")
      });
  } 


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbErD/

Answer (score 0):

`$.map()` is a clean, expressive way to do that:

```
var sample_data = $.map(name_array, function(type) {
  return { 
    name: type, 
    data: window[type + '_data']
  };
});
```

Whether you use a for-loop or `$.map()` (which is a for-loop under the hood too), it's important to distinguish between using `window[string]` and `eval(string)`.  Building a string to use as a window key is *not* the same thing as using eval and doesn't share its vulnerabilities.

For example, `window['alert("doevil")']` harmlessly returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can get shorter code using [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

```
var sample_data = $.map(name_array, function(value, index) {
  return {name: value, data: eval(value + '_data')};
});
```